# Text on screen with GLUT

Tags: opengl, glut

I'm struggling to make text appear on screen in GLUT.

Is it possible without Freeglut.h?

EDIT:
How do I implement it into a loop?

Comment: We are not here to do your work for you, you need to find out yourself and test it for yourself, then if you encounter any coding related problems you can post a question... Though, hint `glutBitmapString()`

Comment: you will get better results if you try your own implementation first, then come and look for guidance when you encounter a specific obstacle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible without Freeglut.h?

Yup.  `glutBitmapCharacter()` and `glutStrokeCharacter()` are both in the regular `glut.h`.

`freeglut.h` just adds `glutBitmapHeight()/glutBitmapString()` and their stroked equivalents.

> EDIT: How do I implement it into a loop?

The straightforward way:

```
void MyBitmapString( void* font, const std::string& str )
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i )
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter( font, (int)str[i] );
    }
}
```

Use `glRasterPos()` or `glWindowPos()` for positioning.